# Timeline on mathematics postdoctoral reasearch proposal

Tags: mathematics, application

I am applying for a postdoc in mathematics and I have to include a research proposal with the usual info and also timescale. This bugs me a lot. I am doing theoretical research, I don't have any simulations or experiments of any sort. So this question about timescale seems absurd to me. I could guess approximately how long it will take me to de the task I am listing, but honestly I see no point in that. How can I know how long will I need to do something? For my PhD I spent a whole year completely stuck at on (vital) point and once I moved from there everything was sorted out rather fast.

So should I guess some timescale and ignore the possibility of being horribly wrong? How detailed do I have to be? Are there any examples I can look at?

Comment: I think the goal here is to make sure you have a plan, not that you have an infallible plan. No matter what you do I think you need to demonstrate that you've thought it through carefully and know what is feasible and what is not.

Comment: Does the demand for a time scale come from the mathematics department that you're applying to, or does it come from the higher administration because of a failure to distinguish mathematics from the experimental sciences? If it comes from the higher administration, then you shouldn't worry; just write something fairly reasonable and assume the mathematicians who read your application will ignore it. If the request comes from the mathematicians, then you probably should worry, and should perhaps reconsider whether you really want to be in  that department.

Comment: @AndreasBlass ah, yes. It's not the department that wants this.